# Оборачивание в вектор данных без копирования

Tags: c++

К примеру, я получаю указатель `const void *` на некоторый массив однородных данных (массив) и количество элементов в нем. Это может быть, к примеру, 10 `int`-ов. Для удобной работы с этими данными лучше, конечно, использовать вектор, но проблема в том, что их нужно копировать. Где-то читал, что в 20-ом стандарте собираются ввести аналог `string_view` для векторов, что позволило бы избегать ненужного копирования, но что можно сделать сейчас?

Comment: Можете попробовать написать кастомный аллокатор

Comment: Сейчас можно использовать разные реализации `array_view`, тот же `gsl::span`.

Comment: Не понимаю: если вы пишете программу на низком уровне то зачем вам вектор? А если нет, то зачем вам void*?

Comment: Я больше обратил бы внимание  на  организацию производства,  чем о том, как сэканомить  на  ручках и бумагах...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 1) кто сказал что я пишу программу на низком уровне; 2) "ручки и бумаги" в вашем понимании это сколько? Для меня 10М к примеру, это то, на чем можно сэкономить - для вас нет?+

Comment: Если нужно сделать stl-like контейнер из двух указателей на внешние данные, посмотрите на ranges. Пока они доступны только как библиотека в составе boost. Вам нужна make_iterator_range, принимающая два указателя.